# jQuery I'm using to make the rows of my table sortable is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm re-writing a project of mine to better align with [the best practice documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#page.html). I'm most of the way there, but it seems the jQuery I'm using to make the rows of my table sortable is not working. When I inspect the raw HTML of the table when it loads following the async call, I noticed that the sortable classes that the [jQuery sortable widget is supposed to embed](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) is not there (I can see it in my old code).

I have the relevant code duplicated on this sheet, but [I'll include it here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14C38YjTEQn9djlJxFx0XfVWfnD3jsIYbgr8NQdpqPSM/edit?usp=sharing):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= include('1.1 openPackV2Stylesheet'); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <table id="awayLineup">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Rtg</th>
            <th>Season</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Team</th>
            
            <th>OB</th>
            <th>Out</th>
            <th>Walk</th>
            <th>Single</th>
            <th>Single+</th>
            <th>Double</th>
            <th>Double+</th>
            <th>Triple</th>
            <th>Homer</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <?!= include('1.1 openPackV2Javascript'); ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

1.1 openPackV2Javascript

```html
<script
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    var awayLineup = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayAwayLineup)
      .getLineupV2();
  });

  function displayAwayLineup(awayLineup){
    // $('.loading').style.display("hidden");
    var tbody = $('#awayLineup > tbody');
    for (i in awayLineup){
      tbody.append(
        '<tr><td class="demographics">'+awayLineup[i][54]+'</td><td class="demographics">'+awayLineup[i][52]+'</td><td class="demographics">'+awayLineup[i][0]+'</td><td class="playerName">'+awayLineup[i][3]+'</td><td class="demographics">'+awayLineup[i][4]+'</td><td class="demographics">'+awayLineup[i][7]+'</td><td class="cardData"><span class="circle">'+awayLineup[i][32]+'</span></td><td class="cardData">'+awayLineup[i][33]+'</td><td class="cardData">'+awayLineup[i][34]+'</td><td class="cardData">'+awayLineup[i][35]+'</td><td class="cardData">'+awayLineup[i][36]+'</td><td class="cardData">'+awayLineup[i][37]+'</td><td class="cardData">'+awayLineup[i][38]+'</td><td class="cardData">'+awayLineup[i][39]+'</td><td class="cardData">'+awayLineup[i][40]+'</td></tr>')
    }
  }

  // make tables sortable

  $(window).on("load", function(){
    $("table tbody").sortable({
      helper:function(e,row){
        var originalCells = row.children();
        var cloneRow = row.clone();
        cloneRow.children().each(function(index){
          
          $(this).width(originalCells.eq(index).width());
        
        })
        return cloneRow;
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your script, it seems that jQuery UI is not loaded. So, how about the following modification?

##### From:

```
<script
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    var awayLineup = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayAwayLineup)
      .getLineupV2();
  });
```

##### To:

```
<script
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayAwayLineup).getLineupV2();
  });
```

- In your script, `var awayLineup =`  of `var awayLineup = google.script.run` can be removed.

#### Reference:

- [jQuery UI](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries#jquery-ui)